# Filter lists by only objects that have property values that exist in every list

Tags: c#, .net, performance, list, dictionary

So I have a `Dictionary<DateTime, List<MyObject>>`

```
public class MyObject
{
    double A {get; set;}
    double B {get; set;}
    double C {get; set;}
}
```

Basically what I need is to find the pairs of values `A` & `B` (don't care about `C`) that exist in at least one `MyObject` in every list.

I could do many `foreach` on top of each other, but I feel like that may not be the most efficient way.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
var result = dictionary.Select(x=> x.Value
                                    .Select( y=> new 
                                           { 
                                               A = y.A, 
                                               B = y.B
                                           }).FirstOrDefault()
                       ).ToList();
```

Where `dictionary` is your dictionary.

Comment: Let me give this a shot, very clean looking. I like it.

Comment: @slandau sure thing. Please let me know if that suits your need. Thanks

Comment: Won't this return a bunch of default dynamic objects if the item is not in one of the lists? @Christos